# hangfire BackgroundJob.Schedule is running on server time only. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, datetime, hangfire

I am scheduling a task on hangfire but,it doesnt trigger at my local time(India Standard Time). If i set it to say 2030/3/3 10:00:00 am it will trigger only at the server time which has a 5 hour and 30 min differnce and Not at the right time i want.

i have tried doing something like

```
DateTime updatedDate = DateTime.Parse(datetime);
updatedDate = updatedDate.AddSeconds(+30);// add extra 30 sec
DateTime currentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(updatedDate, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
string jobid = BackgroundJob.Schedule<Tasks>(x => x.recurringService(), currentTime).ToString();
```

but it doesnt work at all. Someone please show me a way.

Comment: Is your computer on India Standard Time (IST)? Does `datetime` string give any indication of time zone or its just generic like `2030/3/3 10:00:00 am` ?

Comment: yes DatetTimeKind is unspecified

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your computer is set to India Standard Time (IST). I'm also assuming that `datetime` string gives no indication of time-zone.

After `DateTime.Parse(datetime)`, variable`updateDate` should have its 'kind' equal to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. See `Console.Write(updateData.Kind)`

As per Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttime?view=net-6.0),  If the parameter passed `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, it assumes `DateTimeKind.Local` (which is IST). This means `ConverTime` is converting from IST to IST so no change will be made.

For this to work, you need the `updateDate` to be `DateTimeKind.Utc`

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(updatedDate, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```